# "Forbidden" message is shown when I access a Sinatra app on AppFog

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, paas

I uploaded a simple Sinatra app to AppFog. It worked well on my local machine. But after uploading the app to AppFog, a page with "Forbidden" message is shown when I access to [AppFog domain](http://recall.ap01.aws.af.cm/).

These are appFog logs:

```
====> /logs/stderr.log <====
...
W, [2012-06-01T06:32:54.008426 #28933]  WARN -- : attack prevented by Rack::Protection::IPSpoofing
211.32.146.42 - - [01/Jun/2012 06:32:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 - 0.0002
10.0.64.157 - - [01/Jun/2012:06:32:54 UTC] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 9 - -> /
W, [2012-06-01T06:32:54.393022 #28933]  WARN -- : attack prevented by Rack::Protection::IPSpoofing
211.32.146.42 - - [01/Jun/2012 06:32:54] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 - 0.0002
10.0.64.157 - - [01/Jun/2012:06:32:54 UTC] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 403 9 - -> /favicon.ico
```

I did not use `Rack::Protection::IPSpoofing` in my code, but I get those errors. `Rack::Utils` is used in helpers block. Is that causing the problem?

The only Ruby code I wrote is following:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'data_mapper'
require 'builder'
require 'sinatra/flash'
require 'sinatra/redirect_with_flash'
require 'haml'

enable :sessions

SITE_TITLE = "Recall"
SITE_DESCRIPTION = "'cause you're too busy to remember"

DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/recall.db")

class Note
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :content, Text, :required => true
  property :complete, Boolean, :required => true, :default => false
  property :created_at, DateTime
  property :updated_at, DateTime
end

DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!

helpers do
  include Rack::Utils
  alias_method :h, :escape_html
end

get '/' do
  @notes = Note.all :order => :id.desc
  @title = 'All Notes'
  if @notes.empty?
    flash[:error] = 'No notes found. Add your first below.'
  end
  haml :home
end

# ...
```

You can check out the whole source codes [here](https://github.com/philipjkim/sinatra-quickstart).

How can I solve this problem? Thanks for any advices.

Comment: FYI, it works well on [cloud foundry](http://recall.cloudfoundry.com/)

Comment: FWIW, it gives me forbidden too. I would try asking them directly. They appear to be injecting modules into your code (similar to what Heroku did on its Bamboo stack, which they changed with Cedar). Their documentation seems quite lacking to me, so again, I think asking them directly would be best. (or try Heroku, that's my other idea :)

Comment: This also happens on EngineYard hosting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an easy fix, try adding this:

```
set :protection, :except => :ip_spoofing
```

We are patching our nginx soon to fix this issue, but this work around will help for now.